# How to filter some folder/files from maven during project's build?

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml, maven-jar-plugin

I have this file from `spring` at `./META-INF/spring/props.properties` that I would like **not** have it in my built `.jar` when I ran `mvn clean package` or `mvn deploy`. I **don't** want to provide this file for security purposes.

I'm trying to add this on my `pom.xml` but isn't working.

```
<build>
  ...
  <resource>
      <directory>META-INF/spring</directory>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
      <includes>
          <include>props.properties</include>
      </includes>
  </resource>
  ...
</build>
enter code here
```

Comment: Did you mean `<excludes>` instead of `<includes>`?

Comment: I tried that already but still no succes @Tunaki.

Comment: Try with `<directory>src/main/resources/META-INF/spring</directory>` and `<excludes>
          <exclude>props.properties</exclude>
      </excludes>`

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to exclude them from your build, you still want them into your classpath I guess, but you don't want them as part of your final jar, hence your entry point is not the `resources` element but the Maven Jar Plugin configuration.

Check from its official documentation, [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html) how to exclude resources from the packaging.

Below a possible snippet:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>**/spring/props.properties</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

To exclude a file from being built the pom should look like.

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
  ...
    <resources>
       <resource>
          <directory>META-INF/spring</directory>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*</include>
          </includes>
          <excludes>
             <exclude>props.properties</exclude>
          </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
  </build>
</project>
```

To only exclude it from the jar:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*</include>
          </includes>
          <excludes>
             <exclude>META-INF/spring/props.properties</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

And for a war file:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <packagingExcludes>META-INF/spring/prop.properties</packagingExcludes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```